# Is there a common way to get a polymer element's dataset or attributes?

Tags: polymer

I used "paper-input" and "paper-button" in my own polymer element, since the `e.target` is not the element which bind the dataset and attributes,  the way to get dataset in event handler is different. Is there a common way to get a polymer element's dataset or attributes?

```
<dom-module id="login-form">
<template>
    <div>
        <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <paper-input id="username" >
                <paper-icon-button on-click="clearInput" data-elmid="username" suffix >
                </paper-icon-button>
            </paper-input>

            <paper-button class="custom indigo" data-hello="world" on-click="loginValidate">
                Login
            </paper-button>
        </form>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    (function() {
        Polymer({
            is: 'login-form',
            clearInput: function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.dataHost.dataset.elmid);
            },
            loginValidate: function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.dataset.hello);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your binding is slightly incorrect.

To bind a `data-` attribute and be able to access it with the `dataset` property, use **`$=`** in `data-foo$=value` [[*]](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding). Otherwise, Polymer converts the attribute into a camelCase property on the element (i.e., `data-foo=` would be accessed by `element.dataFoo`, whereas `data-foo$=` would be `element.dataset.foo`).
In your example, Polymer created a `dataElmid` property on `<paper-input>`, and `dataHello` on `<paper-button>`.

Here's the corrected example:

```
<paper-input id="username">
    <!-- change `data-elmid="username"` to  `data-elmid$="username"` -->
    <paper-icon-button on-click="clearInput" data-elmid$="username" suffix >
    </paper-icon-button>
</paper-input>

<!-- change `data-hello="world"` to  `data-hello$="world"` -->
<paper-button class="custom indigo" data-hello$="world" on-click="loginValidate">
    Login
</paper-button>
```