# Reading data-attribute from element inside iron-list

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I create a list of divs using an `iron-list` like this:

```
<iron-list items="[[chats]]" as="item" style="height:500px;">
    <template>
        <div class="item title" data-recipient$="[[item.recipient]]">
            <iron-icon class="big" src="../icons/games.svg"></iron-icon>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-list>
```

I have a Polymer method which is called later-on and loops the `div.title`.

I can then manage to set their color, but I can not manage to read out the data-attribute:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.style.color = "red"; // works
    console.log(el.getAttribute("data-recipient")); // prints out null
});
```

Why is that?

Comment: acoording to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496583/is-there-a-common-way-to-get-a-polymer-elements-dataset-or-attributes) you can try `console.log(el.dataset.recipient);`

Comment: el.dataset.recipient returns "undefined"

Comment: then you have undefined value because item.recipient doesn't exists.. This have to work.. You should be able to call it via `el.getAttribute` or `el.dataset`. If you inspect that element in developer tools do you see value of that attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside a Polymer method, avoid using `document.querySelector()` because it queries the entire document instead of only your element's local DOM, and this function would not be able to query the element's shadow DOM. You should use [`this.$$('.title')`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#instance-methods) instead.

However, I cannot reproduce the symptom you're seeing in this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mRNYzo?editors=1010) (i.e., `el.dataset.recipient` and `el.getAttribute('data-recipient')` both return the expected value).