# How to know if my Polymer element is currently visible

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In my application, there is a messaging custom element.

I want to send a certain notification to a user only in case that element is not visible at the moment (or out of the viewport).

How could that be done with Polymer?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to test whether an element is visible in the viewport (see [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)):

```
Polymer({
  ...
  _onSomeEvent: function() {
    var targetEl = /* ... */;
    if (!this._isElementInViewport(targetEl)) {
      // send notification to user
    }
  },

  _isElementInViewport: function(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
  }
});
```

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328783/reading-data-attribute-from-element-inside-iron-list), I'm assuming you're asking in the context of `<iron-list>`. If, for example, you'd like to determine the viewport-visibility of a specific list item, you could test whether the item's index is between [`<iron-list>.firstVisibleIndex`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list/iron-list#property-firstVisibleIndex) and [`<iron-list>.lastVisibleIndex`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list/iron-list#property-lastVisibleIndex).

```
Polymer({
  ...
  _onSomeEvent: function() {
    var targetEl = /* ... */;
    if (!this._isElementInViewport(targetEl)) {
      // send notification to user
    }
  },

  _isElementInViewport: function(el) {
    var index = /* get index of el */;
    return index >= this.$.myIronList.firstVisibleIndex &&
           index <= this.$.myIronList.lastVisibleIndex;
  }
});
```